# Is there a way to replace an iframe's document with another without copying?

Tags: javascript, iframe, document

I have an iframe `ifr` and a document `doc`. I want to set the iframe's content/document using a loaded document.

What I have now is:

```
ifr.contentDocument.open();
ifr.contentDocument.write(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
ifr.contentDocument.close();
```

What this does is that it **copies** the content of the document in HTML into the iframe's document.

What I want is to make the iframe display the loaded document without copying it. In that case another iframe can display the same document instance and any modifications will be done in both iframes.

Is this possible in any way in JavaScript?

Comment: No, that's not possible, each iframe has its own browsing context, and sharing documents between the browsing contexts is not possible.

Comment: @Teemu ok, is it possible to share at least a node? Like say for example, the ```<html>``` root node?

Comment: No, that's not possible either, a node can have only a single parent element. You can [clone nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) without `document.write`, though.

Comment: Ok, I may have found a solution, I'm trying to create multiple iframes and replace them in the parent node. The problem is, that iframes, when created, they don't have a window neither a document. They have to be added to a window for everything to be initialized. Is there a way I can do this? btw, I tried ```<object>``` and got the same issue.

Comment: @bsella see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61502773/2813224) It is entirely dependent on default HTML behavior, no JavaScript and although there's CSS -- it is purely optional.

Comment: @zer00ne This is not what I want. I need to save one instance of a document and be able to load it in any iframe. This is quite the opposite.

Comment: @bsella when you save a document ... describe your interpretation of what *"save"* means. Can you exit your browser, then comeback to the edited page? Or are the edits saved in localStorage and then reapplied to document? Or is this edited page saved onto a file? Is a server involved at all or is this purely client-side? BTW you said, *"What I want is to make the iframe display the loaded document without copying it."* My answer does exactly that. Are you sure you know what an iframe is? It's a window looking into a webpage, the src is the location of document not the document itself.

Comment: I understood, that you want a live instance of the document on the main window (or in another iframe) to be shown in another iframe too, and while somehow editing the main document, all the changes would be reflected on that iframe too, immediately.

Comment: @zer00ne what I meant by "saving" a document is just creating an instance of a ```contentDocument``` that can be displayed on any number of iframes without being copied. Apparently, this is not possible.

Comment: @bamia the browsing content of each iframe are unique. If a browserA opens a webpage and browserB opens the same webpage -- what happens with browserA shouldn't be seen in browserB and vice versa. This is behavior for client-side. What you need is server-side control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep your HTML-code in a browser storage and automatically synchronize it between your windows and frames

Answer (score 0):

The following technique works with pages in the same domain as well. The editing of a webpage without cloning can be done by moving the page. Let me know if that interests you and I'll update this answer accordingly.

1. Add `[name]` attribute to `<iframe>`.

   ```
    <iframe name=''...></iframe>
   ```
2. Assign an arbitrary value to `[name]` of `<iframe>`.

   ```
    <iframe name='portal'...></iframe>
   ```
3. Add an `<a>`nchor.

   ```
    <a href=''...></a>
   ```
4. Assign the url to `[href]` of `<a>`.

   ```
    <a href='//example.com'...>Example</a>
   ```
5. Add `[target]` to `<a>`.

   ```
    <a href='//example.com' target=''...>Example</a>
   ```
6. Assign the `[name]` value of `<iframe>` to the `[target]` of `<a>`.

   ```
    <a href='//example.com' target='portal'...>Example</a>
   ```

---

#### Demo

**Note:** SO blocks YouTube so review this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/9uwb67qv/8/)** for a fully functional demo

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 700 small-caps 3vw/1.5 Verdana, sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  width: 99%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='//example.com' target='portal'>Example</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='//player.vimeo.com/video/411293670' target='portal'>Vimeo</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='//www.youtube.com/embed/4r7wHMg5Yjg' target='portal'>YouTube</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <iframe name='portal' src='about:blank' width="560" height="315" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</main>
```